# Pods are not created on new nodes

Tags: raspberry-pi, kubernetes, nodes, raspbian, scaling

When i create a sample nginx pod with some replica's to test my kubernetes cluster. i get a strange output. The pods create themself on the first node but on the 2 other nodes they stuck at status "Container creating"

When i describe the pods (only the ones on the other nodes) they give this error message

```
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  1m    kubelet, xploregroup  Failed create pod sandbox.
  Normal   SandboxChanged          1m    kubelet, xploregroup  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
```

the strange part is that all node have all exactly the same configuration (cloned the image from the master) and i joined them all exactly the same way. 
The pods get distributed normally but only the pods on node1 is running .

Can someone direct me to the same direction :(

[EDIT]
journalctl -u kubelet gives this error

```
Mar 12 13:42:45 kubeMaster kubelet[16379]: W0312 13:42:45.824314   16379 cni.go:171] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Mar 12 13:42:45 kubeMaster kubelet[16379]: E0312 13:42:45.824816   16379 kubelet.go:2104] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

The problem seems to be with my network plugin. In my /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10.kubeadm.conf . the flags for the network plugins are present ? environment= kubelet_network_args --cni-bin-dir=/etc/cni/net.d 
--network-plugin=cni

Comment: Hi , can you add the logs of init container `kubectl logs -f POD_NAME -c  INIT_CONTAINER_NAME`?

Comment: the output of that command gives me this:




Error from server (BadRequest): container nginx is not valid for pod my-nginxxxxx-695c999c66-cq8hk

Comment: Hi, you can restart the kubelet

Comment: i did that with the following commands
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet.service
right now i commented the kubelet network args line in the kubelet service kubeadm conf file (from above). and the init is restarting i will keep this post updated in a minute. 
----following this tutorial https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43815

Comment: Nope still nothing :(

Comment: that's strange. Are you having your Cluster on-premise or on cloud ?

Comment: on-premise , the hardware are 4 Raspberry pi's.

And the strange thing is the cluster worked before on the raspberry pi's. When i cloned my sd card to an image file and shrinked it so that i can add other pi's to be added to my small cluster it stopped working. I reversed engineered (ish) to where it went wrong but everything works in every stap :(

Comment: PerhapsIPTables can be a issue here. you can flush the iptables rule and retry to add the node to the cluster.

Comment: unfortunately even after flushing iptables it doesn't work

Comment: Your CNI plugin is not working. Which one are you using?

Comment: @whites11 
I used weaver  and tried these two commands to set the plugin up
1) sudo kubeadm init --config kubeadm_conf.yaml
then i found a more specific command and tried that too
kubectl apply -f “https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d ‘\n’)”

Comment: I don't know weave much. Try having a look at weave's pods logs

Comment: which plugin do you use ?

Comment: The thing is i think this is a raspberry error and not a kubernetes one.
When i install rasbian lite on all the pi's and install kubernetes manually. weaver network works and gives no error, it's after i read the image to a .img file and burn it to copy it to the nodes that the errors start.
I'm now trying to figure out why that happends cause my os works fine. if there was a corrupting when i read it to the .img file it won't get up. Someway down the line something happends and kubernetes get's all crazy